# [Airflow]Prevent new tasks from being accidentally run during partial dag reruns

Tags: airflow

In airflow, if you add a new task to a dag and then clear its downstream task in an old dag run, airflow will first run the new task you just added.

For example:

A DAG was run on T:
A >> B

On T+1 we added a new task C in the middle:
A >> C >> B

Now if we don't do anything, and someone clears task B on T, then it will first trigger C, which is not something we want.

Currently we have a manual script to mark a new task as "success" in all historical dag runs, because we don't want the new task to trigger automatically when a downstream task is cleared. I am wondering if there is a less-manual solution to address this concern? It's quite annoying to manually mark success in historical dag runs every time we add a new task.

Answer (score 0):

Since `C` is in the middle of the workflow I'm not sure there is a simple way to handle this. I would probably create a new DAG with a new `start_date`. In the old DAG I would add an `end_date` thus you can backfill both safely if needed.

There might be another solution but i'm not sure this will work well.
You can try also to add `start_date` for task `C`.
Probably you have a `star_date` defined in `default_args` where you use it for all your tasks. What you need to do is to overwrite this for task `C`.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 4, 1),

}
with DAG(dag_id='stackoverflow',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval="@daily",
         ) as dag:
    A = DummyOperator(task_id='A')
    B = DummyOperator(task_id='B')
    C = DummyOperator(task_id='C', start_date=datetime(2021, 5, 12))
    
    A >> C >> B
```

This might be tricky because you define here only the new dependency. This solution would work for sure if the workflow was: `A >> B >> C` but I never tested it over this use case. In any case my recommendation is to use the first solution of creating a new DAG.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Elad. My concern with the fist solution is that we will end up with hundreds of dags. Does Airflow have a way to manage "basically the same dag but with different end dates"?

Comment: Also, the goal here is not to prevent task C from running in old dates. But more like preventing it from *accidentally* being run. A lot of time we do want to run those new tasks in older dates, but it will be a deliberate decision.

Comment: Airflow doesnt know that the two dags are related business wise. Hundrends of dags are not really an issue also im not sure that in a working production environment you are changing and adding tasks to your dags hundrends of times. You will get to a stablw point evntualy.